# How to remove formula (query, if etc) without losing current sheet value in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

how to remove Formula without losing value in google sheet.
i know how to copy value without formula (CTRL + SWIFT + C). but i want remove all formula (ifs, query, xlook etc in current sheet)  without losing value in current sheet. how to remove formula without losing value in google sheet?

[image]

Comment: CTRL+A ... CTRL+C ... CTRL+SHIFT+V

Comment: Are you looking to have a  script for it?